# What all do we need to test in the application is undergoing a Mongo upgrade?

Tags: manual-testing, database, exploratory, system-testing

The application I'm working on is going to have a Mongo upgrade from Version 3.3 to 3.4
What all do we need to test and should care about apart from the general system sanity and regression?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read what is involved in an upgrade from version 3.3 to 3.4? Have you read any release notes? Clues often reside there.

Comment: Are you responsible for testing both the upgrade and the full application, or just the application?  Is this a single application, or is this an application that would be rolled out to many users, outside of your control?

Answer (score 3):

With any kind of framework or database upgrade like this, after I'd covered system sanity and critical path regression, I would go through the release notes looking for any changes likely to impact my application and test around each of those.

I'd be particularly careful with these areas, in this approximate order of priority:

- Breaking changes
- Deprecated functionality
- Removed functionality - if you have a process to modify your application to remove deprecated functionality as soon as possible, removed functionality shouldn't cause problems, but it can still catch you.
- Bug fixes where the bug impacts some functionality your application uses.
- New functionality adding to or enhancing aspects of the system your application uses (because new bugs are most likely to cluster around new features)